# Prove the triangle inequality is valid for the norm $\lVert f \rVert =(\int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert ^2 dx)^{1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

I.e, prove $\lVert f+g \rVert\ \le \lVert f \rVert + \lVert g \rVert$ for all $f,g$ in $C^\infty [0,1]$,
  $$\lVert f \rVert =(\int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert ^2 dx)^{1/2}$$

I think we're supposed to use Cauchy-Schwarz: $\lvert \int_0^1 f(x)g(x) dx \rvert \le \left( \int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert ^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_0^1 \lvert g(x) \rvert ^2 dx \right) ^{1/2}$

So far I've got $\lVert f+g \rVert\ = \left( \int_0^1 \left( \lvert f(x) + g(x) \rvert \right) ^2 dx \right) ^{1/2} \le \left( \int_0^1 \left( \lvert f(x) \rvert + \lvert g(x) \rvert \right) ^2 dx \right) ^{1/2} = \left( \int_0^1 (\lvert f(x) \rvert)^2 + (\lvert g(x) \rvert)^2 + 2 \lvert f(x) \rvert \lvert g(x) \rvert dx \right)^{1/2} \le \left( \int_0^1 (\lvert f(x) \rvert)^2 dx \right) ^{1/2} + \left( \int_0^1 (\lvert g(x) \rvert)^2 dx \right) ^{1/2} + \left( 2 \int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert \lvert g(x) \rvert dx \right)^{1/2}$

I'm also not sure about the last step...

Comment: Search about Minkowski Inequality's

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to do all these calculations. The norm induced from *any* inner product obeys the triangle inequality as a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, so just state that your norm is induced from the inner product
\begin{align}
\left<f, g\right> := \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\overline{g(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I think Alex actually intends to prove ||f|| is certainly a norm.

Just one comment: Use $||f+g||^2 $ to avoid square roots.

> $||f+g||^2 = ||f||^2 + ||g||^2 +2 |<f,g>| \leq ||f||^2 + ||g||^2 +2 ||f||||g|| = (||f||+||g||)^2$,

and we are done.